# how to achieve url rewrite in htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite url in htaccess file.

I wrote the following code in htaccess file. but it doesn't work.

Here is my Code :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [NC]
```

How can i write following url in given format

```
http://www.site.com/play/player.php?/id=9 to http://www.site.com/play/player/9
```

How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Place this .htaccess in `/play/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /play/

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rule in the question is only going to match requests that end in .htm - what  you want is probably something like:

```
RewriteRule ^play/player/(.*)$ /play/player.php?id=$1 [L]
```